# Conditional Formatting of Cells to the LEFT/RIGHT of Cells that Contain Specific Text Beginning With

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, vba

I'm looking for a formula or VBA code that can apply conditional formatting, specifically the fill color, to blank cells to the left or right of cells that contain specific text that begins with: "P". I've attached a screenshot of exactly what I'm looking to achieve.

[Excel Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZLEV.png)

I want the fill color of cells in column A to change to blue if the cell next to it in column B contains text beginning with "P" and Pink if the the text is "T", etc.

The way I had achieved this before was with a macro to copy the data from column F and paste it into columns A,G,M then apply conditional formatting to those columns with the rule: Cell Value begins with "P", and then changing the fill color and text to the same color so as to appear solid.

It's hacky but works, unfortunately when printing, the cell's text will still show up against the fill background color. Which isn't the end of the world but am wondering if there is a more correct way to achieve this. Is there a way to offset which cells the formatting applies to? Any help is appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select columns A, F and M with F1 as the Active Cell. Create a new CFR using the following formula.

```
=or(iferror(left(e1)="P", false), left(g1)="P")
```

[image]

The problem with creating this in VBA is the formula; there is no column to the left of column A and any union of the three columns will always treat A1 as the 'active cell' regardless of how the union is created. .Range("G:G, M:M, A:A,") is the same as .Range("A:A, G:G, M:M"); A1 is the 'active cell'. One solution would be to temporarily switch to xlR1C1 where RC[-1] can be used to reference the non-existent column to the left of column A.

```
Option Explicit

Sub meh()
    Dim refStyle As Long, xlR1C1formula As String

    'store original reference style
    refStyle = Application.ReferenceStyle
    'make it xlR1C1 reference style
    Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        With .Range("A:A, G:G, M:M")
            .FormatConditions.Delete

            xlR1C1formula = "=or(iferror(left(rc[-1])=char(80), false), left(rc[1])=char(80))"
            With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=xlR1C1formula)
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 5
                .NumberFormat = ";;;"
            End With

            xlR1C1formula = "=or(iferror(left(rc[-1])=char(84), false), left(rc[1])=char(84))"
            With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=xlR1C1formula)
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 22
                .NumberFormat = ";;;"
            End With
        End With

        'switch back
        Application.ReferenceStyle = refStyle
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: btw, if you want the cell text/value to 'disappear' then don't set the font color; set a Custom Number Format of `;;;`.

Comment: Thank you Jeeped for both of those great solutions. However I'm having a bit of trouble implementing this with vba. When I follow your solution in the gif manually it works perfectly as expected, but when I try to use a macro, column M does not get formatted.Here is the [code](http://imgur.com/a/loQWj)  I'm usingand here is the [result](http://imgur.com/a/8CEwo). Any help is always appreciated thank you!

Comment: See my VBA solution above. I've used char(80) and char(84) to determine P and T since I hate doubling up double quotes within a quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is make a Defined Name through Formulas > Defined Names > Define Name, called Here, with the following formula:

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4))`

Then, under Home > Styles > Conditional Formatting > New Rule, use this formula on the cells you want to be affected:

`=IF(AND(Here="",OR(LOWER(LEFT(OFFSET(Here,,1),1))="p",LOWER(LEFT(OFFSET(Here,,-1),1))="p")),TRUE,FALSE)`